# The error "requires SystemVerilog extensions" while declaring an error

Tags: verilog, register, error

What's wrong with the following code? The array "FIFO" is declared correctly, but an error appears. Can you please help how to fix this?

```
module fifo(
    input clk, 
    input [7:0]data_in ,
    output reg [7:0] FIFO [0:8]
);

integer i;
always@(posedge clk) begin
       for(i = 8; i > 0; i=i-1) begin
          FIFO[i] <= FIFO[i-1];
       end
       FIFO[0] <= data_in;
end
endmodule
```

Error (10773): Verilog HDL error at fifo.v(29): declaring module ports or function arguments with unpacked array types requires SystemVerilog extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what it says: you have a two-dimensional output port which is an unpacked array.

This is a packed array: `output reg [7:0] FIFO`
This is an unpacked array: `output reg FIFO [0:7]`

Therefore your two-dimensional array is an unpacked array.

Verilog allows only packed arrays for ports.
If you want two or more dimensions you need to compile with System-Verilog.